# Ocultar categorias en grafico "Dona" de Highcharts

Tags: html, jquery, highcharts, jsfiddle

estoy trabajando con la librería highcharts utilizando el gráfico de tipo "Dona". El punto es que lo dividí en categorías dentro de las categorías y necesito ocultar una de ellas y no logro hacerlo. De ante mano, Gracias.

ejemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/6bk19vaz/

```
 var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
categories = [
        "Cumple", //OCULTAR SUBCATGORIA,
        "No Cumple"
        ],
        data = [
        {
            "y": 70,   
            "color": "#e6b54a",         
            "drilldown": {
                "name": "Cumple",// SUBCATEGORIA INICIO,
                "categories": [
                "DATO 1",
                "DATO 2"
                ],  
                "data": [
                50,
                20
                ],// SUBCATEGORIA FIN

            }
        },
        {
            "y": 30,
            "color": '#850f5b',
            "drilldown": {
                "name": "No Cumple",
                "categories": [
                "> 0",
                "Limite"
                ],
                "data": [
                20,
                10
                ]
            }
        }
        ],
        browserData = [],
        versionsData = [],
        i,
        j,
        dataLen = data.length,
        drillDataLen,
        brightness;


// Build the data arrays
for (i = 0; i < dataLen; i += 1) {

    // add browser data
    browserData.push({
        name: categories[i],
        y: data[i].y,
        color: data[i].color
    });

    // add version data
    drillDataLen = data[i].drilldown.data.length;
    for (j = 0; j < drillDataLen; j += 1) {
        brightness = 0.2 - (j / drillDataLen) / 5;
        versionsData.push({
            name: data[i].drilldown.categories[j],
            y: data[i].drilldown.data[j],
            color: Highcharts.Color(data[i].color).brighten(brightness).get()
        });
    }
}

// Create the chart
Highcharts.chart('chartConectadas', {
    chart: {
        type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: ''
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: ''
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            shadow: false,
            center: ['50%', '50%']
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '%'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'DATO',
        data: browserData,
        size: '50%',
        dataLabels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.y > 5 ? this.point.name : null;
            },
            color: '#ffffff',
            distance: -30
        }
    }, {
        name: 'DATO',
        data: versionsData,
        size: '50%',
        innerSize: '70%',
        dataLabels: {
            formatter: function () {
                // display only if larger than 1
                return this.y > 1 ? '<b>' + this.point.name + ':</b> ' +
                this.y + '%' : null;
            }
        },
        id: 'versions'
    }],
    responsive: {
        rules: [{
            condition: {
                maxWidth: 400
            },
            chartOptions: {
                series: [{
                    id: 'versions',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }]
            }
        }]
    }
});
```

Comment: Cual categoria deseas ocultar?

Comment: la subcategoria dentro de "Cumple"

Comment: ¿Te refieres a algo como [esto](http://jsfiddle.net/hesecq93/)? ¿O algo más [simple](http://jsfiddle.net/erq7w9o1/)?

Comment: Algo como el primero, la cosa es que necesito ocultar una categoría dentro del gráfico sin que su espacio desaparezca, algo como un visibility: hidden de CSS, es decir, que desaparezca pero que aun ocupe su espacio.